# How to control tplink smart plug with HTTP post API in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, rest

How to make a Powershell script that gets a token from HTTP post that saves it and than using that token (that changes periodically) does another HTTP post to control it on or off?

Here's a way to get a token in tasker app on cellphone:

https://wap.tplinkcloud.com

```
application/json

{
 "method": "login",
 "params": {
 "appType": "Kasa_Android",
 "cloudUserName": "tttttt@mail.com",
 "cloudPassword": "tttttt",
 "terminalUUID": "96e4cd54-83d3-4c57-b910-57110cc2b803"
 }
}
```

this is result

```
{"error_code":0,"result":{"accountId":"5502236","regTime":"2019-01-08 
07:43:04","countryCode":"US","riskDetected":0,"email":"ttttt@mail.com","token":
"c10aad35-ATQ5GxNOsloCalmkQPAtvb0"}}
```

Relay toggle on

https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=%Token

```
application/json
{"method":"passthrough", "params": {"deviceId": 
"800604DDC9D2BF255C6A4D04587A95031AB4C0AC", "requestData": "{\"system\":
{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":1}}}" }}
```

Relay toggle off

https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=%Token

```
application/json
{"method":"passthrough", "params": {"deviceId": 
"810604DDC9D2BF255C6A4D04587A91031AB4C0AC", "requestData": "{\"system\":
{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}" }}
```

It works on an app in the phone. How to do it in windows Powershell?

When I make a basic HTTP post script, not this one, it works only when you load Powershell and than manually write it; not when I double click it.